# What did I study?

Tags: knowledge, letters

My puzzle is to solve what I studied when I was 15.

> **LETTER 1: SECOND LETTER**
>   A song written by someone who likes to be on the other side.
>   **LETTER 2: FOURTH LETTER**
>   When you drink this, it makes you strong.
>   **LETTER 3: FIRST LETTER**
>   Usually combined with feta in Greece
>   **LETTER 4: THIRD LETTER**
>   The capital of a country which lies in the second largest rain forest of the world.
>   **LETTER 5: THIRD LETTER**
>   A country which entered the EU in 2013
>   **LETTER 6: FIRST LETTER**
>   Someone who did his/her last film in 1961.
>   **LETTER 7: SIXTH LETTER**
>   An internet browser initially released in 2007.
>   **LETTER 8: FIRST LETTER**
>   The name of the first element in the fourteenth column in The Periodic Table.
>   **LETTER 9: FIRST LETTER**
>   When you smelt this, you can look through it.
>   **LETTER 10: THIRD LETTER**
>   A region in a country which is south of the Alpine.
>   **LETTER 11: THIRD LETTER**
>   A crop which is major commercial in the US and Canada. Usually, this is processed into juice.
>   **LETTER 12: FIRST LETTER**
>   The surname of the presumptive nominee of the Republican Party for President of the United States in the 2016 election.
>   **LETTER 13: FIFTH LETTER**
>   The central reference of the religious Judaic tradition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## ANSWERS TO CLUES!

> 1. <s>Break on Through - R</s> or *Hello* - **E**
>  2. (kind of retrofitting this one) Calcium - **C**
>  3. <s>Spinach</s> or Olive - <s>S</s> or **O**
>  4. Kinshasa - **N**
>  5. Croatia - **O**
>  6. Monroe - **M**
>  7. Safari (Windows release) or Midori (thanks @cpj) - **I**
>  8. Carbon - **C**
>  9. Sand - **S**
>  10. (another retrofit) Campania (thanks @APrough) or Lombardy - **M**
>  11. Cranberry (or Peaches, thanks @APrough) - **A**
>  12. Trump - **T**
>  13. Torah - **H**

So you studied

> ECONOMICS MATH

Comment: Letter 1 isn't right

Comment: Great! Almost complete!!!

Comment: Some suggestions for the remaining - Campania and peaches.

Comment: 7 is probably Midori, Safari has been around since 2003.

Comment: @cpj Yeah I had trouble with a few of these, couldn't find super definitive answers, so I went with "close enough" - I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: 1 is possibly R**e**d Hot Chili Peppers

Comment: That can’t be right. The 2 is *obviously* Guinness!

Comment: Como is not a region (I live there)!

Answer (score 4):

Partial solution:

LETTER 1: SECOND LETTER
A song written by someone who likes to be on the other side.

> H**e**llo by Adele

LETTER 3: FIRST LETTER
Usually combined with feta in Greece

> **O**il or **O**lives

LETTER 4: THIRD LETTER
The capital of a country which lies in the second largest rain forest of the world.

> Ki**n**shasa

LETTER 7: SIXTH LETTER
An internet browser initially released in 2007.

> <strike>NetSu**r**f or Conke**r**er</strike>

LETTER 8: FIRST LETTER
The name of the first element in the fourteenth column in The Periodic Table.

> **C**arbon

LETTER 9: FIRST LETTER
When you smelt this, you can look through it.

> **S**and (glass)

LETTER 12: FIRST LETTER
The surname of the presumptive nominee of the Republican Party for President of the United States in the 2016 election.

> **T**rump

Comment: Good but Letter 7 isn't right